# CLOCK_MONOTONIC Max value

Tags: c, linux, time

When will clock_gettime() return a smaller value, using CLOCK_MONOTONIC, due to reaching it's maximum value? I don't mean the little warps that have been described as bugs, but something like a counter reset.

Is it time measured, or is it related to the absolute number of ticks?

I have to implement a timer (1 or 2 second intervals), and i don't need that much precision. But the aplication may be running several hours without restarting. (i estimate 1 day max).

I wan't to be shure i won't make any mistakes that may lead to it stop comunicating.

Does timerfd already takes care of this issue?

Answer (score 7):

As struct timespec uses a time_t value for seconds, the complete range that can be covered is at least 68 years. Given the definition of CLOCK_MONOTONIC as starting at some arbitrary point, in theory clock_gettime could overrun anytime. In practice, you only need to worry about this if your app runs for some decades. But, if you're paranoid, make a wrapper function that complains loudly and kills the application if a timer wraparound happens.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've run a few tests, and seems that in my box (linux), the Monotonic clock actually starts at boot time (or very close to it). So good news to me, as it seems less likely to overrun.

Comment: Still I'm not shure that this is defined as a timespec from base. Acording to the documention i've read, it's connected to the clock's ticks, so there should be some absolute counter of these ticks. Depending on the system's resolution, this could overrun a lot faster than the decades you refered. Can anyone backup or disprove this line of thinking? I've a test ongoing, and for now (~4 hours), no abnormal behaviour was detected.

Answer (score 3):

CLOCK_MONOTONIC, as implied by the "monotonic" name never goes back in time, it is always growing. Will not change if the user or another process (like NTP) changes the "wall" clock on the machine.
CLOCK_MONOTONIC is the right timescale to use in timers. It can eventually roll over but even that can be handled cleanly if you do it carefully. Use the same type of variable for the internal timer.

For example the following code will work OK eve if the clock wraps around.
Note: kDelayInterval has to be smaller than the wrap around period (this is normally not a problem).

```
struct timespec current_time;
struct timespec last_update = {0,0};
  .
  .
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ¤t_time);
  if((current_time.tv_sec - last_update.tv_sec) > kDelayInterval)
  {
    .
    .
    .
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &last_update);
  }
```

Comment: The tests i made, indicate that it won't roll over after 23 hours (on the arm processor i'm working on), and that's about enought for me. I'm putting a safeguard in the test, case current.tv_sec is smaller than inicial.tvs_sec, i reset the timer. I can afford to miss one cicle, so that should do it. Thank you for you answers.

Comment: Just one comment. i don't think you code works, actually, but correct me please, if i'm wrong. If the clock rolls over, current_time.tv_sec is smaller than last_update.tvsec. So current_time - last_update will be negative, wich will be smaller than kDelay interval for a long period, just before the clock rolls over again (assuming it rolls over at the same value). That's the kind of situation i really want to avoid.

Comment: The nice thing about doing the substraction and then the compare is that the roll over is handled nicely. (the negative result will wrap arround the same way as the roll over). If the clock variables (tv_sec) are unsigned the roll over will be handled nicely. If the clock variables are signed you may have a problem.

Comment: If tv_sec is signed then it all depends on what clock_gettime returns after the rollover. If the next number after MAX_POSSITIVE is MIN_NEGATIVE it will work OK, however if the next number after MAX_POSSITIVE is -1 then it will not work ok. You may have to consider the uptime of the system, type of tv_sec and the implementation of clock_gettime, but as a general portable way this works OK.